# Nhibernate Map composite element

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have DB view ALL_ATM_DEV_SATTRIB_VALS

```
DEVICE_ID   ATTRIB_ID    INT_VALUE    STRING_VALUE    DATE_VALUE

1           13           null         10.0.3.50       null
1           14           0            null            null
1           15           null         null            null

2           13           null         10.0.3.51       null
2           14           2            null            null
2           15           null         null            null
```

Entity objects

```
public class AttributeValue: IAttributeValue
{
    public virtual string StringValue { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateValue { get; set; }
    public virtual int? IntValue { get; set; }
}

public class Device : IDevice
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }        

    public virtual IDictionary<long, IAttributeValue> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping file(hbm)

```
<class name="Device" table="DEVICES" lazy="true" >

<id name="Id" column="ID" ></id>

<map name="Values " batch-size="10" table="ALL_ATM_DEV_SATTRIB_VALS" lazy="true">
  <key column="DEVICE_ID" />
  <index column="ATTRIB_ID" type="System.Int64" />

  <composite-element class="AttributeValue">
    <property name="StringValue"  column="STRING_VALUE" />
    <property name="DateValue"  column="DATE_VALUE" />
    <property name="IntValue"  column="INT_VALUE" />
  </composite-element>
</map>

</class>
```

---

**Selecting** dictionaries values work correctly, but when i tried use it in Linq expressions

```
List<IDevice> a = dc.Get<IDevice>()
                    .Where(x=>x.Values[13].StringValue
                                          .ToLower().Contains("10.0.3"))
                    .ToList();
```

nhibernate throw exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create element join for a collection of non-entities!
```

In the object `Device` I need to have `IDictionary`. Key is ATTRIB_ID(long), Value is `AttributeValue`

Comment: Is it the same if you drop the I, so the dictionary is `IDictionary<long, AttributeValue>` Also, `name="Values "` should not have trailing space, though I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: What type is `dc` in your example code? `IQueryable`? I think the problem is, that you are using `IDevice` in your LINQ query. The exception message tells me that you should use the type defined in the .hbm file which is `Device`. Does that work? I don't have a IDE available to confirm that, therefore I post it first as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nhibernate can't create a sql-query use `IDictionary<long, IAttributeValue>` because IAttributeValue don't map in hbm as entity.

But i solved this problem.

I replaced the mapping of one `IDictionary` to three simpler :

```
 <map name="StringValues" table="ALL_ATM_DEV_SATTRIB_VALS" lazy="true" fetch="select">
  <key column="DEVICE_ID" />
  <index column="ATTRIB_ID" type="System.Int64" />
  <element column="STRING_VALUE" type="System.String"/>
</map>
<map name="DateValues" table="ALL_ATM_DEV_SATTRIB_VALS" lazy="true" fetch="select">
  <key column="DEVICE_ID" />
  <index column="ATTRIB_ID" type="System.Int64" />
  <element column="DATE_VALUE" type="System.DateTime"/>
</map>
<map name="IntValues" table="ALL_ATM_DEV_SATTRIB_VALS" lazy="true" fetch="select">
  <key column="DEVICE_ID" />
  <index column="ATTRIB_ID" type="System.Int64" />
  <element column="INT_VALUE" type="System.Int64"/>
</map>
```

I use this maps **only for create result sql-query**, thats why `lazy=true` is present, and 
never access to them in the entity `IDevice`

Data of this maps selected an another sql-query at once, because lazy initialization would cause n+1 sql-queries on DB.

Linq query in my question transformed in :

```
List<IDevice> a = dc.Get<IDevice>()
                .Where(x=>x.StringValues[13].ToLower().Contains("10.0.3"))
                .ToList();
```

In `IDevice` entity defined three maps :

```
    public virtual IDictionary<long, long> IntValues { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<long, string> StringValues { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<long, DateTime> DateValues { get; set; }
```